# Using require/require_relative method in def initializer is ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did not find the correct place to use the require method in any documentation. I understand that it is desirable to use the require method at the very beginning of the script, but is it possible and how correct is it to use the require method in the initializer class constructor?

Usually i make like this
`require 'my_file'`

how good is it to do the option below

`class MyClass`
 `def initialize`
`require 'my_file'`
`end`
`end`

Read require method documentation

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible"? Why don't you just try it, that will quickly tell you whether it is possible or not. What do you mean by "correct"? What do you mean by "good"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did not find the correct place to use the require method in any documentation.

The "correct" place depends on your requirements and also on your coding style.

> is it possible and how correct is it to use the require method in the initializer class constructor?

It is possible. Whether it is "correct" or not depends on your definition of "correct" and it depends on what you want to do.

`require` only does three things:

1. Search for a file in the load path.
2. Check whether the file was already run.
3. If it wasn't, run the file.

That's all `require` does.

If you `require` a file in the initializer, `require` will *only* run when you call the initializer (which is usually when you instantiate a new object).

If you need some functionality from the file before you instantiate an object, you are out of luck, since the `require` will not have run.

Also, you will run `require` *every time* you instantiate an object, but since `require` only runs the file once, that will simply be a waste of time, since it will still search for the file and check whether it was already run every time.

Lexically nesting a call to `require` like this can also be confusing. Someone who is not familiar with Ruby may assume that by `require`ing `myfile` inside the `initialize` method, the definitions inside `my_file` might be scoped purely to the `initialize` method, but that is obviously not the case: `require` simply runs the file, it does not perform any scoping. The definitions inside `my_file` will be defined wherever `my_file` says they are.

In the same vein, someone who is reviewing your code might assume that *you think* that this creates some sort of scoping and might now wonder whether your code has some sort of bug or (worse) security leak based on that assumption.

And note that "someone who is reviewing your code" might very well be yourself in two years, when you have no idea anymore why you wrote the code this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it on top of the file before the class declaration. So you have:

```
require 'my_file'

class MyClass
 def initialize
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, it will work correctly, but it's highly unusual. I guarantee this will raise questions in code review.

Normally, requires are placed on top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the `require "./file_name"` is not recommended to use in the constructor method as it is often used to create the instance variable and particularly: if you are going to use an instance or global variable from that required file class as a parameter to the `initialize` (constructor) method of the current class, it may end up with an error.

You may use these ways to `require` the file at the top of the class:

```
require 'my_file'

class MyClass
    def initialize
       puts "this is a constructor"
    end
end
```

or you may also `require` it just before calling your class is highly recommended to use `require`

```
class MyClass
    def initialize
       puts "this is a constructor"
    end
end

require 'my_file'
object = MyClass.new
object.some_method
```

This allows you to use all the instance, class, method, object...etc.. in your current class.

Comment: "it may end up with an error" - if you are using mutable global state at all, it will bite you, sooner or later. If it's immutable, you're fine. Location of a `require` has no effect on this.

Comment: Yes! @Sergio , i agree with you and thank you for your correction :)